# Reducing grammar to LL1

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, compiler-theory

I have the following grammar:

```
A-> AB|CA
B-> Bd | ef
C-> e|f
```

I removed left recursion as follows and my grammar looks as below:

```
A->CAA'
A'-> BA'
A'-> epsilon
B-> efB'
B'->dB'
B'-> epsilon
C->e
C->f
```

The problem I'm having after this is ambiguity when constructing parse table for this.
Can someone point to me in the right direction for this?
Or I think I'm making mistakes in calculating First and Follow Sets for Parse Table.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Woops.  The original grammar does not derive any string of terminals, so trying to make it LL(1) is pointless.  The first production always produces a form with an `A` in it, and there is no other derivation from `A`.  Did you skip something or have a typo in your post?

**To be fixed:**

Your left recursion removal is good.  Now you need the prediction sets for each production:

```
A->CAA'            first(CAA') = { e, f }
A'-> BA'           first(BA') = { e }
A'-> epsilon       follow(A') = follow(A) = { end of input }
B-> efB'           first(efB') = { e }
B'->dB'            first(dB') = { d }
B'-> epsilon       follow(B') = { end of input }
C->e               first(e) = { e }
C->f               first(f) = { f }
```

There are no ambiguities here because the predict sets of each right hand side corresponding to any given left hand side have null pairwise intersections.

What ambiguity were you seeing?

Comment: Wouldnt Follow(A) include First(A') as well as a result of production A-> CAA'? That was the mistake I was making.

Comment: @user3638992 Yes!  Good catch. I missed that. Let me think about it.

Comment: @user3638992 Actually, looking at it more closely, the grammar never derives any terminal stringg because the first production (not in your conversion, but in the original), will always produce a new `A`.  Did you skip a production?